# cocotb-config: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

Im running into an issue with cocotb make files cant be found??

```
$ git clone https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb  
Cloning into 'cocotb'...  
$ cd cocotb/examples/endian_swapper/tests  
$ make  
make: cocotb-config: Command not found  
Makefile:60: /Makefile.inc: No such file or directory  
make: cocotb-config: Command not found  
Makefile:61: /Makefile.sim: No such file or directory  
make: *** No rule to make target '/Makefile.sim'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

This got answered here:
https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/902

Need to run PIP install, Documentation is being updated too.